# What is the max number of function keys for a keyboard?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, keyboard

Quick backstory:
I am looking at building a custom mechanical keyboard (custom case and firmware) I was looking around and found a site that gave me keycodes for javascript and it shows there are 32 function keys (https://keycode.info/). On an Apple keyboard, it comes with 19 function keys (at least for the one a relative has). I know a typical keyboard only has 12.

The question:
Is there a specification for the number of function keys that a keyboard should be able to support, and where can I find it?
Since support may be different on different machines, what is the max number of function keys that are supported on Windows, Mac OS, and Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many keyboards had <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F14</kbd>, and [some Macs through <kbd>F16</kbd>](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/937344). [The IBM 1397000](http://www.seasip.info/VintagePC/ibm_1397000.html)  and others had <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F24</kbd>. That said, I don't know of any keyboard with 32 function keys.
Actually, function keys are defined through [<kbd>F35</kbd>](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/silk-test/195/en/silktestclassic-195-help-en/STCLASSIC-1BA4AA17-KEYNAMES-REF.html), on Unix X Window machines!

However, there are various ways to *send* keycodes for *all* the F-keys. For example, [ISO/IEC 9995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9995#Function_keys) specifies use of <kbd>Shift</kbd> for Level 2 keys and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> for Level 3. The [VT100 terminal](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-f13-through-f24-vt100-terminal-dos) used a combination of <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> to send the keycodes. Some VT100 emulators used left and right shift keys for different F-key levels.